# CCNet - send email with exception message

Tags: cruisecontrol.net, ccnet-config

How do I configure CCNet to send emails with the build exception message if there is one?

I am using notification "Always" for notification type, but so far I have been getting just the success or fail emails.

Comment: Can you post a snippet of your configuration?

Comment: In my Email Publisher I have

Comment: (Ignore the incomplete above.) In my Email Publisher I have: includeDetails="TRUE". I am getting the error notification, but just not the *compile* error message. If CCNET craps out then that exception does make it to the email body. The perfect solution would be to attach the log file to the email, but it's proving to be harder than it should be.